# round a number to a range of numbers Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays:
`X = np.linspace(0,100,101)` and `Y = np.linspace(0,100,15)`. How to make the values of one array be rounded to the values of the other array. that is, I finally have an array of size 101 but the values of the array **X** came close to the nearest values of the array **Y**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
Y[np.absolute(X[:,np.newaxis]-Y).argmin(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use X array to produse Y array. Like this:

```
Y = X[::len(X)//15]
```

But it'll give you a little biased numbers.

For this particular case you also can use simple round function:

```
Y = np.array(list(map(round, Y)))
```

In general, you can solve this by searching for the minimal difference between elements in arrays:

```
Y = X[[abs(X-i).argmin() for i in Y]]
```

Comment: In the last case, if you want to change X array, just replace X and Y.